# "regardless whether" vs. "regardless of whether"

Tags: prepositions

> But for statistical purposes, a 14-year-old boy who works at least one hour a week is officially considered employed, **regardless whether** he is paid.

Is "of" obligatory after **regardless** in **regardless whether**, or, as the Chicago Tribune's journalist writes, one can decide if using it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both phrases are acceptable in Standard English.  However, *regardless of whether* has become [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=regardless+whether+%2F+regardless+of+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) over the last hundred years, and some prescriptivists now consider the other form a mistake.  Because of this, I recommend you stick to *regardless of whether*.

[image]

Language Log also had an interesting [post on this subject](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4361), which you may be interested in reading.

Comment: I think "regardless of" is the better answer. When I looked up "regardless" here http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/regardless the examples used "regardless of". Examples on some other dictionary sites were the same way, so I think this should be the common usage.

Comment: @user3169 Yes, I agree.  That's why I said the same thing in my answer.  However, I feel it would be inaccurate to call *regardless whether* non-standard.